# ES(Primary and disaster setup/cluster)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, disaster-recovery, elastic-stack

What is the architecture which can be used for ES considering need for disaster recovery requirement. Basically we need to maintain 2 clusters setup located in different locations. The request will go to Cluster2 only in case of cluster1 is down. Challenge here is maintaining index data consistency between the 2 clusters.

Does ES supports this type of setup? Or can anybody suggest how we can achieve this?. Also how we can achieve full load indexing and incremental refresh of data in to these clusters.

Thanks,Rakesh

Comment: As of now have created 2 clusters for 2 DC's. While indexing updates are written into both the clusters parallaly.  Also while querying ES, if there is connect exception, the request will be sent to other cluster. Any comments?.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested configuration won't work since you'll need to replicate data between the clusters and whenever you'll switch there will always be some data loss.

What you probably want to do is create a bigger cluster with a higher RF (replication factor) so even when some nodes go down you're still up and running.

If you're in the cloud you can spin the cluster up across a few zones (I'm referring to AWS but there is probably an equivalent term among the other cloud providers) which will make the cluster resilient to a zone outage.

You can also spin a multiregion cluster but I wouldn't start with that.

Comment: Cluster defined across data-centers/zone might impact the search performance. One reason is network latency between the DC's, while ES internally does farwarding/searching requests.

Comment: @RMS while this is theoretically true, we're doing it across dozens of ES clusters (again, using AWS) and don't feel any latency pain! This point becomes valid when we're running multiregional clusters which is why I wrote that I wouldn't start with that.